# SSIS transaction with MSDTC service

Tags: sql-server, ssis, transactions

So I have been struggling with handling transactions in SSIS. My requirement is to achieve transaction without enabling MSDTC service and I have partially achieved that but I just got another error which I feel like is one of the many bugs in SSIS. I used execute SQL task and  explicitly mentioned begin tran and commit/rollback tran in my package. My package is working fine. All the tables are enclosed in a sequence container. I have a condition where one output from one table goes in 2 different tables and that's where the problem is. The funny part is even the package fails, I will still see insert in only these two tables. SSIS is shown in the attached image. I have disabled two tables. These two tables take input from Frholdsum and even if the package fails and there is no data in FDR holdssum tables. Microsft never ceases to amaze me :(. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQRJq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set RetainSameConnection on your ConnectionManager to true.

https://munishbansal.wordpress.com/2009/04/01/how-to-retain-same-data-connection-across-multiple-tasks-in-ssis/

Comment: I have already done it. I have only one connection manager and 
Set RetainSameConnection = true a;ready.

Comment: And transaction is working fine if I disable those two data flow task. Please see the image attached.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine if I explicitly write delete statements after rollback ran like this:

rollback tran; delete from dbo.UCOP_ENDOW_INVEST; delete from dbo.ucop_fdr_attrib ;

I shouldn't have to do this though :(